# How can i install JCE?

Tags: 16.04, java

How can i install Java Cryptography Extension (JCE)Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files in Ubuntu 16.04.

Please tell me also that how can i check that JCE is installed in my system or not?

Comment: JCE is now part of using Oracle JDK 1.8-151 or higher version. No need to install separately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get them at this PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt update
sudo apt install oracle-java7-unlimited-jce-policy
```

How can you tell if it is installed? This command will succeed :)

For a more upto date Java 8 version run

```
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
```

[source](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webupd8_java/xenial/main/base/oracle-java7-unlimited-jce-policy)

Comment: Thanks for me this solved long lasting issue with logstash after upgrading it.
without this the p12 key files from google throw an error

Comment: why does it say `oracle-java7-`?

Comment: @Raf This is an old answer, I am updating it

Comment: Shouldn't the package name be `oracle-java8-unlimited-jce-policy`

Comment: @Raf Not according to the repository, ppa:webupd8team/java

Answer (score 20):

Openjdk comes already installed with JCE

A quick test to see if you have the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files installed:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/jrunscript -e 'print (javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("RC5") >= 256);'
```

The command should return **true** if JCE is installed.

Comment: This is really helpful!

Comment: Very helpful answer

Answer (score 1):

To see if it has installed, search for the installer. You can try to check in the `var` directory and into `cache`.
Follow this path:`/var/cache/oracle-jdk7-installer/ls.` This will give you all the details about JCE and the Policies.

Answer (score 0):

Installing JCE for JDK7, no longer works from the webupd8 team repository. Follow these instructions for JVM 6 or 7:

1. Go to the Oracle Java SE download page.
2. Scroll down ... Under "Additional Resources" section you will find "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy File."
3. Download the version that matches your installed JVM, for example, UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7.zip.
4. Unzip the downloaded zip.
5. Copy local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar to the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security (Note: these jars will be already there so you have to overwrite them).

Taken from [here](https://dzone.com/articles/install-java-cryptography-extension-jce-unlimited).